How do I remove the default blue outline colour and the default hover effect on MUI Form
I want to be able to remove the default blue outline when focused `and the default hover effect that comes with the Form control of MUI (variant outlined). I just want the actual colour of the border at all times. No outline colour and no hover effects colours``


I have tried multiple things including applying sx etc. None worked satisfactorily

